# Raspbian - Apache server not accessable over the internet

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, apache-httpd, port-forwarding

I want to use my raspberry pi as a webserver. I installed and configured apache and enabled port forwarding on my router, but it seems that I do something wrong. I really searched a lot before, but I can't find an appropriate answer.

Here is what I've done so far:

**Apache**

***ports.conf:***

```
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

***apache2.conf***

I only added the line

```
ServerName public_ip
```

***sites-available/default-ssl.conf***

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName public_ip:443
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        ServerSignature On
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I activated the site via

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

**iptables**

```
iptables -L
```

gives me following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Netstat**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0     64 192.168.1.12:22         192.168.1.10:30007      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

**Router Thomson TG782**

***Port forwarding***

[image]

***Firewall on router***

Currently deactivated.

**Conclusion**

http and https works in the LAN. What am I missing?

Comment: apache will not understand `ServerName` with an IP (at least not under a virtual host with `*:443`.  Instead use a proper hostname even if it is just in the `/etc/hosts` file (e.g. `public_ip myserver.mydomain myserver`).  Moreover, to get inside a virtual host the `HTTP` request must have the `Host:` header.

Comment: Are you sure your ISP allows default web server ports to go through?  Unless you have a static IP, it is very unlikely.  One way to test it would be to add another port forwarding rule with a non standard port (such as 8080) in your router that would point to port 80 or your local server and to test it with `http://1.2.3.4:8080` (replacing 1.2.3.4 with your public IP).

Comment: Can you make the conclusion clearer, does it work or not? (like the detail else where)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of grochmal and Julie Pelletier it works now! (see comments section of my question)

I changed:

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 8443 https
</IfModule>
```

**sites-available/default-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName server_name_from_hosts_file:8443
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        ServerSignature On
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

**apache.conf**

```
ServerName server_name_from_hosts_file
```

**Port forwarding**

New port forwarding rules for the Ports 8080 and 8443.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to do these two commands.

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

I saw that you only did:

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

Comment: You're correct. I didn't mention it in my original post, but I executed both commands. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll update it